# java application servers with php and exploded war support

Tags: java, php, web-services, web-applications

i am looking for a java application server to install on my machine to deploy a project in an EXPLODED war way but i need this server to support php. i tried using tomcat 6 with apache 2.2 but i failed in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) is Caucho Technology's 100% Java implementation of PHP 5 released under the Open Source GPL license.

Or just use Apache to handle PHP + Tomcat or Resin to handle WARs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a servlet-based PHP engine, for example:

- http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/php.html
- http://tools.herberlin.de/phpservlet/index.shtml

(they might not implement all the official PHP features) or a CGI bridge webapp (to run PHP in CGI mode).